# nginx container seems unable to reach OSC responder *LetsEncrypt): how to debug?

Tags: docker, nginx, certbot

Very new to docker, I'm trying to setup an nginx docker that uses https with a LetsEncrypt certificate that is already existing and working correctly outside docker. Within the container it raises an error that seems to be related to reachability of external host from within the container:

```
nginx_1    | 2019/11/29 00:10:03 [warn] 1#1: "ssl_stapling" ignored, host not found in OCSP responder "ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org" in the certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/customersite.it/fullchain.pem"                                                      

nginx_1    | nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, host not found in OCSP responder "ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org" in the certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/customersite.it/fullchain.pem"
```

I'm using `nginx:latest`. How can I debug if the container can in fact reach ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org? `ping` is not available nor 'host', but a request from outside reaches correctly port 80, that makes me think the networking is correctly setup (default bridge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a firewalling problem. I inadvertently deleted some rules needed to the linux kernel to route from inside the containers to outside. In this case, I needed to restart docker services and the iptables rules where added.

It took me a while to realize, I downloaded a debian image and started a container that had some network debugging tools (ping and host). At that point, I discovered that a simple "ping" working in a container on my laptop was not working in the remote.

```
docker run --rm -it debian:buster ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
```